# Передача значения int

Tags: c#, ссылки, бинарное-дерево, int

Имеется задача реализовать индексацию в бинарном дереве поиска, поэтому решил считать у каждого узла количество его поддеревьев. Что можно сделать, чтобы вес, скажем, самого верхнего элемента (точнее, количество его поддеревьев) изменялся по мере добавления в дерево новых элементов?

Comment: Очевидно, что пройти до корня вверх, увеличивая счётчики.

Comment: В условии задачи сказано не использовать перечисление для этого. У меня была идея сделать подобную штуку, т.к. уже реализован IEnumerable, но увы

Comment: Думаю, что стоит изменять счётчики по мере добавления/удаления элементов.

Comment: а как тут поможет то, что _уже реализован IEnumerable_?

Comment: В теории можно было бы просто перечислять до момента, пока счетчик не достигнет искомого индекса и в т. случае возвращать элемент. Но возвращать значение по индексу программа должна за O(h)